# Different output with c++ pi approximation

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vastly different output C++ monte carlo approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592502/vastly-different-output-c-monte-carlo-approximation)

On my 64-bit ubuntu computer, the following code works as expected, and returns a close approximation for pi with both algorithms. However, on the lab machine, where I must demo the code, a 32-bit rhel 3 machine, the second algorithm always returns 4, and I cannot figure out why. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
/*
 * RandomNumber.h
 *
 *  
 *      
 */

#ifndef RANDOMNUMBER_H_
#define RANDOMNUMBER_H_

class RandomNumber {
public:
RandomNumber() {
    x = time(NULL);
    m = pow(2, 31); //some constant value
    M = 65915 * 7915; //multiply of some simple numbers p and q
    method = 1;
}
RandomNumber(int seed) {
    x = ((seed > 0) ? seed : time(NULL));
    m = pow(2, 31); //some constant value
    method = 1; //method number
    M = 6543 * 7915; //multiply of some simple numbers p and q
}
void setSeed(long int seed) {
    x = seed; //set start value
}

void chooseMethod(int method) {
    this->method = ((method > 0 && method <= 2) ? method : 1); //choose one of two method
}

long int linearCongruential() { //first generator, that uses linear congruential method
    long int c = 0; // some constant
    long int a = 69069; //some constant
    x = (a * x + c) % m; //solution next value
    return x;
}

long int BBS() { //algorithm Blum - Blum - Shub
    x = (long int) (pow(x, 2)) % M;
    return x;
}
double nextPoint() { //return random number in range (-1;1)
    double point;
    if (method == 1) //use first method
        point = linearCongruential() / double(m);
    else
        point = BBS() / double(M);
    return point;
}
private:
long int x; //current value
long int m; // some range for first method
long int M; //some range for second method
int method; //method number
};

#endif /* RANDOMNUMBER_H_ */
```

And the test class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include "RandomNumber.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
cout.setf(ios::fixed);
cout.precision(6);
RandomNumber random;
srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
cout << "---------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "   Monte Carlo Pi Approximation" << endl;
cout << "---------------------------------" << endl;
cout << " Enter number of points: ";
long int k1;
cin >> k1;
cout << "Select generator number: ";
int method;
cin >> method;
random.chooseMethod(method);
cout << "---------------------------------" << endl;
long int k2 = 0;
double sumX = 0;
double sumY = 0;
for (long int i = 0; i < k1; i++) {
    double x = pow(-1, int(random.nextPoint() * 10) % 2)
            * random.nextPoint();
    double y = pow(-1, int(random.nextPoint() * 10) % 2)
            * random.nextPoint();
    sumX += x;
    sumY += y;
    if ((pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2)) <= 1)
        k2++;

}
double pi = 4 * (double(k2) / k1);
cout << "M(X)  = " << setw(10) << sumX / k1 << endl; //mathematical expectation of x
cout << "M(Y)  = " << setw(10) << sumY / k1 << endl; //mathematical expectation of y
cout << endl << "Pi = " << pi << endl << endl; //approximate Pi

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typically, `long` is 32 bits on 32-bit architectures and 64 bits on 64-bit architectures. Perhaps you're running afoul of this?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it is similar, however the answer was wrong and I'm no longer using arguments to set the value, and the issue still exists.

Comment: Then please un-accept the accepted answer, and edit the old question instead. Editing the question will bump it, so it won't be lost in the "noise".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `pow` returns a `double`, which loses precision at the low end.  Converting to `long int` for the `%` operator always returns the same result, and so your RNG outputs constant -60614748.

```
x = time(0)                 1354284781
pow(x, 2)                  1.83409e+18   0x1.973fdc9dc7787p+60
(long int) pow(x, 2)       -2147483648    0x80000000
(long int) pow(x, 2) % M     -60614748
```

The fix is to change `x = (long int) (pow(x, 2)) % M;` to `x = x * x % M`, performing all arithmetic within `long int`.  Note that this is still strictly speaking incorrect, as signed overflow is undefined; more correct is to use `unsigned long`.

Comment: Interestingly, this changes the output from 4.000 constantly to 3.99480 or thereabouts,

Comment: Anything can happen, because, as @ecatmur himself noted, this still triggers undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The truncation to `long` in `BBS()` causes the same "random" number to be generated.

PS. The return from the `pow` function is a number, which is too big to be represented in your machine's `long` type.  When doing the conversion to `long` this results in undefined behaviour. One particular effect of the undefined behaviour might be the result of the conversion to be `0x80000000` or `0x7fffffff` so you end up with a sequence of the same numbers.

Comment: @chilll could you elaborate on this at all?

Answer (score 0):

```
x = time(0)                 1354284781
pow(x, 2)                  1.83409e+18   0x1.973fdc9dc7787p+60
```

A 32-bit int holds a value up to 2^31-1 the value of x^2 is greater than that.